# progress bar for the browsers which don't support html5

Tags: html, actionscript-3

I want to develop a progress bar for all browsers.Is there anything like flash fallback for progress bars which don't support html5,i mean i want to display html5 progress in the browsers which support html5 and action-script progress bar in the browsers which don't support html5 Or is there any polyfill that i can use for this progrress bar?

Comment: Why not just make your own html progress bar the old fashioned way? It would probably be easier (not to mention way better) than using flash as a fallback

Comment: To that end, here's me spending 5 seconds on google:  Scroll to end where:  
https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

Comment: When you say "progress bar", do you simply mean a visual element that looks like a progress bar, or the progress of something specific, say file uploads?

Comment: i am saying about progress bar for file uploads.

Comment: @LDMS,i don't know how to build progress bar in old fashioned way.i am using php.could you please tell me how can i build progress bar in old fashioned way

Comment: @SivaCharan "I am saying about progress bar for file uploas." -- that's a really important part you should mention in your question. So you are asking about a file upload using XHR2 when available, with Flash Player/`FileReference` fallback.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> i am saying about progress bar **for file uploads.**

That's an important detail you should include in your question.

So you are asking for a file upload solution that uses XHR2 with progress events when available, and a Flash Player `FileReference` fallback. This is certainly doable. A library for this probably does exist, have you searched around? A quick search shows [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) as a possible solution.